# Keeping my `client_id` secret?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

How am I supposed to keep my `client_id` secret when using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK on a public website? I can't figure out from the documentation whether calls will only be allowed when coming from domains I've supplied when registering the app, or if there are any other measures to prevent people from just using my `client_id` themselves.

Comment: you can call api from your server and retranslate to client

Comment: @Maxx Not an option, I need to stream audio directly in the browser. In any case, they do provide a JavaScript SDK, what would be the purpose of that if you can't use it? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript